# $_Session not gathering all user information?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

Working on a user website at the moment and having some trouble with this code:

```
 <?php 

 // Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect ("host","a2530897_admin","pass") or die("Could not conenct");
mysql_select_db("a2530897_members") or die ("could not connect to dadabase!");

$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
session_start();

echo "<strong>First Name: ". $_SESSION['first_name']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Last Name: ". $_SESSION['last_name']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Email Name: ". $_SESSION['email_address']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Photo: ". $_SESSION['photo']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Username: ". $_SESSION['username']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Date: ". $_SESSION['date3']."</strong>";

?>
```

This seems to bring up most of the information correctly, first name, last name and email address works. When I try to bring up the photo name, username or the date that was entered with the user information, it doesn't appear and comes up blank? Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting all you session variables? Are you doing anything with your query?

Comment: You code is both vulnerable to SQL Injection as to XSS attacks.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to do it, I'm new to this kind of stuff and not very good at writing code, I find it online and use it, unless it simple stuff. This code sure isn't working though and I can't seem to come up with anything that does, specially to get the picture name.

Comment: Are you trying to get firstname, lastname, email adress etc out of the database and displaying it? Than this is not the way to do it.

Comment: Yeah that is my aim, all of that works doing it this way (probably not the best way to do it) but I am mostly trying to get the image name to appear, once they upload an image it logs the name in their database. But it won't show back up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Session before start session

```
$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
session_start();
```

should be

```
session_start();
$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

As based on username you are fetching record for that user then no need to display information from session variable you can directly display like below

```
session_start();
$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL);

echo "<strong>First Name: ". $row['first_name']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Last Name: ". $row['last_name']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Email Name: ". $row['email_address']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Photo: ". $row['photo']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Username: ". $row['username']."</strong>";
echo "<strong>Date: ". $row['date3']."</strong>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just tried this and still not getting the information back? Name and Email is still working, but nothing else?

Comment: Please check for remaining variable whether your setting session value or not

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: Check in any other script whether value assign for session variable. e.g $_SESSION['first_name'] = 'Some Value';

Comment: // Register some session variables!
  session_register('first_name');
  $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
  session_register('last_name');
  $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
  session_register('email_address');
  $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
  session_register('special_user');
  $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
  
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

Comment: Just found that in the checkuser.php script. Think that might have something to do with this issue ?

Comment: Yes. This is the correct script but it might be case you have written code to set value in session but if value is null then nothing will be set for that value. let say `$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;` this is correct if `$last_name` is null while setting session then your session value will be null.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Just sorted it and it's working perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Is there a way I can rate you for a good answer? I'm new to this site?

Comment: Glad to help you. Simply mark my answer as solutions by clicking tick mark :) That's enough . Enjoy learning